# Too Many View Controllers? (Programming Technique)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm creating an app that will most likely have somewhere around 40 view controllers. Could this slow down my app, and if so, is there a better way to handle the creation and use of these view controllers?

Somebody recommended multiple storyboards, however I don't use storyboards (I believe it's easier to do everything programmatically)

Thanks!
Nick

Comment: Do you plan to stack all 40 at once into a navigation controller? If not, there's no problem until you actually have a problem.

Comment: No way. I'll give it a shot and see what happens, hopefully it works.

Comment: Have you ever developed an app with 40 view controllers without using storyboards?

Comment: By saying slow down, are you talking about the performance when running your app on a phone, or the loading of project, storyboard or whatever from Xcode IDE?

Answer (score 1):

**Use of 40 ViewControllers wont affect your application speed. Unless you deallocate all the objects corresponding to previous viewcontroller upon performing any segue.**

For better speed while opening storyboard in XCode, I prefer splitting to two or more storybords (Module wise, if your application is able to divide). And making the common method invokation using [Follow link](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/02/imp-of-current-method.html)

Happy Coding..

Comment: @NicholasTiwari  Is this aswer sufficent for you? let me know plz